# iOS slow to release images while scrolling (no tableview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, ipad, memory-management

Here is the problem :
I am writing an app which displays some pictures, with a treemap layout (for an example, see https://raw.github.com/beckchr/ithaka-treemap/master/Core-API.png)
This layout is displayed in a UIScrollView. Since many pictures can be added to that scrollview, I want to release the ones which are not on currently on screen. I am not using ARC.

At my point, I know which pictures I should release, and how to do it while scrolling (calling some "unload" method). There is no useless call of that method. The problem is that, when pictures are released, the scrolling stops for a little moment (a few ms, but this is enough to be bad looking, making the scroll kind of "jumping" and slow, not smooth at all).

What I've tried (put in the body of my "unload" method) :

```
imageview.image = nil
performSelectorInBackground:@selector(effectiveUnload) withObject:nil
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0,^(void){
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
imageview.image=nil}
}
```

I think this problem is weird, since there is absolutly no slowing effect with memory allocation, but only with memory release.

Thanks for help, don't hesitate to ask for more information.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a UITableView?

Comment: The main reason is the treemap display. I have some coords for my pictures, which can change (it does not display a list with a stable layout)

Answer (score 0):

did you try `removeFromSuperview` to remove the imageview from scrollview

Comment: No, I did not. I wanted to let the UIImageView in place, to reload the UIImage quickly if needed. I will try to remove the UIImageView and to add it again if I need to. Thanks for this idea.

Comment: Well, it is exactly the same problem. When I `removeFromSuperview` (and `self.imageView = nil`, since I do retain it as a property), the scroll is still stopping a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add more and more UIImageViews - recycle them!
To save as much memory as possible you should follow the UITableView way of recycling views:
1. Once a view has left the visible area, add it to a "views pool" (and remove it from its superview. It's not an expansive operation!)
2. When a new view becomes visible, first check if there's a view in the pool. If not, then create a new view.

I know my answer doesn't answer your question directly, but that's the way to go. Otherwise you'll run out of memory eventually.

Comment: I think it is a good idea, even if it does not answer to the question. The number of UIImageViews can be high, but not infinite. I don't think I could run out of memory as long as my imageviews not displayed are empty. The problem is that it could have some deep impact in my code, so I will do that if I don't have any other choice. Plus, there will still be image releasing, which is the problem of the question.

Comment: Yes, if I comment the imageview.image = nil, there is absolutely no problem, the scroll is perfect, even if I reload images already loaded. The problem really comes from releasing.